# How to structure content dynamically in 2 columns

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, grid

im trying to fit some posts contents in 2 columns dynamically but I can´t find the right approach, can you help me a little?

here are what i'm trying to do

[Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1QCq.png)

I've tried grid but it creates rows and it ended this way with a gap because of the grid row placement, I can't use grid-area because this supossed to be dynamic content so I won´t know when they will be bigger or smaller

[Reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo3sB.png)

Comment: Can you show some of your code that you have tried? You might want to look for existing solution as well. Something like this perhaps? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stack-grid#live-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using flexbox layouts in such cases.

```
{
    display: flex
}
```

To divide the the content in 2 columns, you may use

```
flex-direction: row
column-gap: 12px (whatever is your requirement)
```

and to align items in a stack in each column, you may use

```
flex-direction: column
row-gap: 12px
```

You can checkout other flexbox layout css to customise it according to your needs.